# Bold figure number but not in reference

Tags: captions

I like to have a bold figure number in my captions:

```
\newcommand*\oldthefigure{}
\let\oldthefigure=\thefigure
\renewcommand*\thefigure{\textbf{\oldthefigure}}
```

The problem is, that also when I use `\ref` in my text, the number is getting bold, which is not what I want. How can I fix this, not using any additional package (because I am forced to)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`article` defines

```
\def\fnum@figure{\figurename\nobreakspace\thefigure}
```

so you want

```
\def\fnum@figure{\figurename\nobreakspace\textbf{\thefigure}}
```

(In a local package, or between `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother`)

Answer (score 3):

When <strike>you're</strike><sup>*</sup> someone finding this question due to a similar problem already is using the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package they can define a label format for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
% define label format with a bold number:
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{boldnumber}{\bothIfFirst{#1}{~}\textbf{#2}}
% use the new label format (only) for figures (without the
% optional argument /all/ floats will use the new format):
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=boldnumber}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  foo
  \caption{foo}\label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}
figure~\ref{fig:foo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

<sup>*</sup> I hadn't noticed the requirement “not using any additional package”.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any of the standard class file (`article/book/report`), then you need to add the below code before `\begin{document}`:

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{\begingroup%
  \def\thefigure{\textbf{\arabic{figure}}}%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    #1: #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip\endgroup}
\makeatother
```

**Working:** Definition of `\thefigure` is redefined in `\@makecaption` macro which sets the caption, which is kept inside a group.